# Cygwin_server on Windows 10

Tags: permissions, cygwin, windows-10

I am running windows 10 but whenever I try to run any administrator tasks i.e. change user profile or install software, I am presented a windows dialog box to enter a password for a Privileged Server (I don't know what that is). There is a box to enter the password and below the box it displays [my computer id]/cyg_server where [my computer id] is my computer id.

However, I have tried a few passwords but none of them work. However, one password, shows the error message: Log On failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer. The other passwords just display invalid password.

I installed Cygwin a few months ago but this has only started happening recently. I have Norton anti-virus on my machine so I am not convinced this is a virus.

I would appreciate any help as I think I am going to have to rebuild my machine!!

Answer (score 0):

The `cyg_server` or `Privileged server` is a special user created by `cygwin` when you configure some services like `cygserver`, or the `ssh server`. It is part of the Administrators group but it is only used for service and never for logon. May be your W10 is catching `cyg_server` as first login user between Administrators instead of using the right one.

Suggestion (I don't have W10): login as Administrator and remove the `Privileged server` user.
You can recreate it later, if needed, configuring again the `cygwin services` you installed

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right that Win10 was using the cyg_server before the  Admin. I eventually found out that the cyg_server user id only has delete privileges, so that explains why it couldn't install anything. I've ended up re-installing Win10...and that was a nightmare as well, so something was definitely corrupted by something...yeah!?! I've had Cygwin on my machine for a few months with no issues.